# Google fusion tables data and changing image to markers

Tags: google-maps, show, marker

Here is my problem. I want to set different image to standard markers given by fusion tables. I extract data from the column that contains my points "(coord,coord)" BUT when I associate this coordinates to a marker, this one is not showed! I think that the solution is soooo easy but I can't get it :(. Please read in the section "HERE IS THE PROBLEM" in the middle of this code to have a clear idea. Thanks!!!!

```
 function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.06454, 13.23561), //the center lat and long
    zoom: 9, //zoom

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //the map style
  });


  //make gviz request
  setData();

}

/* GVIZ - get data from Fusion Tables */

function setData() {
  //create a viz query to send to Fusion Tables
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + encodeURIComponent("SELECT dove FROM 781907"));

  //set the callback function that will be called when the query returns
  query.send(getData);

}

function getData(response) {

  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();


  for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

      var row = response.getDataTable().getValue(i,0);


    codeAddress(row);
  }
}


var geocoder;


function codeAddress(latlng) {

// HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!!
// Test show correctly "(lat,lng)" BUT no marker showed on the map!
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = latlng; 
      geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map, 
          position: latlng
//icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/fusion_tables-32.png")

      });

    } 
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**: Based on @Trott's answer, maybe something like this? But still not running. Any advice?

```
function getData(response) {

  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();

  //create an array of row values
  for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    rowtext = response.getDataTable().getValue(i,0);
    var strArr[] = rowtext.split(",");
    document.getElementById("via").innerHTML = rowtext;
    row = new google.maps.LatLng(strArr[0],strArr[1]);
    codeAddress(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try uncommenting the icon line?

Comment: sure :). It semms that the coordinates extracted from fusion tables aren't recognized. If I row.type ... I get "uncategorized"

Comment: Are you sure they are the correct way round? lat/lng many systems store them lng/lat - this has bitten me a few times (kml, looking at you mate) - ah no, they are the right way round for the map itself.. italy right? Whatabout the data you are fetching? Similar numbers? T

Comment: You are aware that fusion tables can be told to geocode addresses dont you? (and you can export as kml)

Comment: latlng needs to be a LatLng object.  In your code above, it's not.  (More in my answer below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geocoder.geocode()` requires a `LatLng` object.  Your variable `latlng` is simply text.  You'll need to find a way to convert it to a `LatLng` object.  Most obvious way is probably to parse it with a regex or some other way and pass the lat and lng to `new google.maps.LatLng()`.   There may be a more elegant solution, but that will work.

If it helps, here's some quick hacking I did to your code to confirm what I wrote above.  I just hardcoded your first pair of coordinates.  You'll still need to write something to parse the data.

```
function codeAddress(latlng) {
//Whoops, latlng is a string.  We need it to be an object.  Let's just hardcode one for demo purposes.
latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(46.0724339, 13.249490000000037);
geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: latlng,
          icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/fusion_tables-32.png")

      });

    }
  });
}
```

**UPDATE:**  If you (@Massimo) want to do it the way you have it in your update, then you need to remove the parentheses and possibly white space.  Try something more like this:

```
function getData(response) {

  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();

  //create an array of row values
  for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var rowtext = response.getDataTable().getValue(i,0);
    var sanitizedText = rowtext.replace(/[\(\)\s]/g, "");
    var strArr = sanitizedText.split(",");
    document.getElementById("via").innerHTML = rowtext;
    row = new google.maps.LatLng(strArr[0],strArr[1]);
    codeAddress(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking about regex but also hoping that that's a better, clear way (tried splitting but not in the right way :S). Don't want to spend more time than I have already done :P, so ... I TRY.

Comment: You still need to get rid of the parentheses and possibly white space.  I've updated my answer to that effect.

Comment: THANKS! This is the solution! (btw "var strArr" not var "strArr[]")